# JavaScript - Reverse ordering of words

Tags: javascript

If I have a string like this:

```
var string = "Text 1 - Text 2 - Text 3 - Text 4";
```

Is there anyway I can reverse it so that it looks like this:

```
var stringReversed = "Text 4 - Text 3 - Text 2 - Text 1";
```

If anyone can tell me how to do this I'd highly appreciate it :)

Comment: Great, perhaps you'd care to post it as an answer to the question, please?

Comment: Well, you can use the "-" in order to break the original string into an array of strings, and then reversing it is trivial.

Comment: What @sircapsalot means to say: People come to this page, not looking for help with their coding problems when they are stuck, but ask for solutions that start at 0. Think about how you'd accomplish your task yourself, then search the web for things like `javascript split`, `javascript reverse`. Trying and failing will get you a lot further than getting the solution handed to you, and when you get stuck, you'll certainly find help for the specific problem there.

Comment: @UweB I see, thanks. Well yes I did give it a shot but I consistently had the problem that the letters were reversing as well as the words. Perhaps I should have specified that in my question :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a one-liner

```
"Text 1 - Text 2 - Text 3 - Text 4".split(' - ').reverse().join(' - ');
// "Text 4 - Text 3 - Text 2 - Text 1"
```

Comment: To be honest, I like both solutions. One is a nice walkthrough, the other one for more advanced users.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is!

```
var string = "Text 1 - Text 2 - Text 3 - Text 4"; // "Text 1 - Text 2 - Text 3 - Text 4"
var array = string.split(' - ') // ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4"]
array.reverse() // ["Text 4", "Text 3", "Text 2", "Text 1"]
array.join(' - ') // "Text 4 - Text 3 - Text 2 - Text 1"
```

The basic idea is to turn it into an array with `split()`, and then reverse it and then put back the pieces together with the `join()`.

Comment: @sircapsalot reverse() is on the array, not the text inside it.

Comment: The split function turns the string into an array

Comment: oops.. silly me. i forgot that split() returned an array. i thought you were reversing the string :)